# Obtaining city model for modification in CityEngine from LiDAR point cloud

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, point-cloud, 3d-model, cityengine

In ArcMap I transformed the point cloud into Multipoints and then into Singlepoints and I obtained this model in ArcScene.

Is it possible to transform these points into 3D objects?

Finally, I would like to get a 3D city model for modification and CityEngine

[image]